# Oozie fork running only 2 forks parallely

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, oozie, fork-join

I am running an oozie workflow job which has a fork node. Fork node directs the workflow to 4 different sub-workflows which in turn are calling shell scripts.
Ideally all 4 shell scripts were suppose to execute parallely but for me only 2 shell scripts are executing parallely.

Could someone help me to address this issue?

Comment: Are you running this on a full cluster or in a Pseudo distributed VM environment?

Comment: Hi Stephen,Thanks for your response. Yes it is a Pseudo Distributed VM environment.

Comment: In the Oozie logs, are the 4 Actions logged as "running" with 4 different `job_xxxxxxx_yyyy` job IDs? If yes, then check in YARN console, are some of these `application_xxxxxxx_yyyy` jobs queued in ACCEPTED mode waiting for available resources? *(note the preffix change, "job" is a pre-YARN legacy thing)*

Comment: Hi Samson, you are right - In Oozie logs, all 4 actions are logged as "running" and in YARN console, the actions which are not executing shell scripts are in ACCEPTED mode.
What can be done in this case to make all actions run simultaneously?

Comment: The problem is almost certainly that you don't have enough capacity on the VM for all the containers to run at once. Each container uses some RAM allocation, and yarn will only execute a certain number while the others queue. If you ran this same workflow on a cluster, I susect all 4 actions would execute at the same time.

Comment: You may be able to change your memory settings in yarn-site.xml to get them all running at once. Look for the setting yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb in /etc/hadoop/conf/yarn-site.xml and enter a higher value and restart your VM to see if that gets things going.

Comment: Increasing the value of yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb in /etc/hadoop/conf/yarn-site.xml worked for me. Thank you guys for responding.